# Suggestions for a IRC client implementation on Web platforms

Tags: php, javascript, html, flash, irc

I want to put an **IRC** client in my webpage. I know there are many clients but **not** opensource ones (I didn't find any). So, do you know some free and open source projects to implement an **irc** client on a webpage?

And what do you suggests in term of implementation? I mean is it a good idea to have one made in **flash**?, one made in **html5**?, one made in **javascript/php**?. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind installing a little server-side code, take a look at the [qwebirc](http://qwebirc.org/) project. This is what Freenode uses for it's web-based chat client.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use [mibbit](http://mibbit.com/) directly then you can at least steal some of the ideas.

Answer (score -2):

This one is an open source client: http://xchat.org/

Comment: Ah well you can write your own quite readily using twisted / nevow / comet.  Here's a tutorial: http://divmodsphinx.funsize.net/nevow/chattutorial/intro.html